# How do I make home screen widget from rss feed?

Tags: android, android-layout, rss, android-widget

This is a three-part question. I am new to Android and am trying to create a new app that reads RSS feeds and shows them on the home screen in the form of a `widget`.

1. What network calls are required to show a well-formatted RSS feed?
2. What layout structures can I use to hold the received content?
3. How can I make the web browser open the link to the RSS feed if the user selects it from this widget?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am new to Android and am trying to create a new app that reads RSS feeds and shows them on the home screen in the form of a widget.

First, the interactive bits of the home screen  are called "app widgets".

Second, this is unlikely to be easy, except perhaps on Honeycomb.

> What network calls are required to show a well-formatted RSS feed?

Ask whoever you are getting the RSS feed from. Typically, it is HTTP. However, if you spend the time to research what "RSS" and "network calls" mean, you will learn that they are largely unrelated. I can give you an RSS feed in the form of a piece of paper, for example.

> What layout structures can I use to hold the received content?

On Honeycomb, you can use a `ListView` for your feed in an app widget.

> How can I make the web browser open the link to the RSS feed if the user selects it from this widget?

Use `startActivity()` to launch an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on the URL.

However, if you spend the time to research what "RSS feed" and "link" are, you will learn that browsers do not know how to display RSS feeds (an XML format). I am guessing that you really mean "open the link to the item from the RSS feed".